# Splitting a list into a string

Tags: python, list

This is my list:

```
animals = ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse']
```

I want to split it so I end up with a string with the three strings inside the list, like this:

```
dog/cat/mouse
```

I have tried using the following code, but it just prints the original list:

```
print [e.split('/')[0] for e in animals]
```

Anything wrong?

Comment: That's not splitting. That's joining, the inverse of splitting.

Comment: This is not "splitting".  When you split something, you end up with more parts than you started with.  You are apparently trying to join the list elements into a single string.

Comment: After reading this question, I found myself imagining a `cleave` string method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't want to `split` you want to `join`, somehow the reverse operation.

```
animals = ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse']
"/".join(animals)
```

Answer (score 0):

Join works great.

If you have a fixed string that you want to populate with a fixed number of list elements, you can also do this:

```
>>> '{}+{}-{}'.format(*(t for t in animals))
'dog+cat-mouse'
```